# Replacing specific line in a file using java

Tags: java, file, str-replace

I need to replace first line of a file. So I am doing it in a usual way by reading the file line by line and replacing the first line and then appending all other line and then finally writing it back. Using `count` variable to count line number as an optimization as it will prevent other `equals()` comparison to run.

In case someone wants to replace nth line, `count` can be tweaked easily for the same.

My question is - do we really need to read whole file even it is known that replacement has to be done in just first line? Is there a way to avoid reading of other lines and still be able to modify this file?

```
private void replaceFirstLine(File file)
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String content = "";

            int count = 0;
            while (line != null) 
            {
                if(count < 1 && line.equals(CURRENT_FIRST_LINE))
                {
                    line = EXPECTED_FIRST_LINE;
                    count++;
                }

                content = content + line + System.lineSeparator();
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(content);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                //Closing the resources
                bufferedReader.close();
                writer.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652706/how-can-i-delete-line-from-txt