# How do I delete only a few character in a file using PrintWriter

Tags: java, printwriter

I created an account system in Java with the following code:

```
while (true) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\nisha\\IdeaProjects\\LeetCode\\src\\com\\company\\Accounts", true), true);
        boolean shouldContinue = false;

        System.out.println("Do you want to create an account (type create) or login to an account (type login) or exit (type exit)?");
        String response = s.nextLine();

        if (response.equals("create")) {
            System.out.println("What do you want your username to be?");
            String username = s.nextLine();

            if (username.equals("exit"))
                return;

            int len = username.length();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nisha\\IdeaProjects\\LeetCode\\src\\com\\company\\Accounts"));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();

                if (line.length() < len)
                    continue;

                if (line.substring(0, len).equals(username)) {
                    System.err.println("Username already exist");
                    shouldContinue = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (shouldContinue)
                continue;

            System.out.println("What is the your value (number) ?");
            String next = s.nextLine();
            int val = 0;

            try {
                val = Integer.parseInt(next);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if (next.equals("exit"))
                    return;

                System.err.println("Not a valid number");
                continue;
            }

            pw.println(username + " " + val);
        } else if (response.equals("login")) {
            System.out.println("What is your username?");
            String username = s.nextLine();

            if (username.equals("exit"))
                return;

            boolean didFind = false;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\nisha\\IdeaProjects\\LeetCode\\src\\com\\company\\Accounts"));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

                if (parts[0].equals(username)) {
                    System.out.println("Your value is " + parts[1]);
                    didFind = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!didFind) {
                System.err.println("Your username was invalid");
                continue;
            }
        } else if (response.equals("exit")) {
            pw.close();
            return;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Invalid option");
            continue;
        }

        pw.close();
    }
```

Another feature I want to add is to delete your account. However, I cannot find a way to delete a certain line from the PrintWriter without deleting the entire file's content. How do I do this?

I researched on a bunch of different websites but all of them don't have append mode on, making it impossible to delete only a few characters.

Comment: this maybe solve ur question<br>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652706/how-can-i-delete-line-from-txt

Comment: You cannot really delete in a file. You can overwrite existing text (e.g., with spaces), which has the disadvantage that you later need to gracefully skip such holes in the file. Or you need to read everything into memory (or another file) and then re-create the old file and write back only what you want to keep. This is not a limitation of Java, but all underlying file access works that way.

Comment: @Robert you don't have to read everything into memory when you use `RandomAccessFile` or the `FileChannel` from NIO